# Scala: list to set using flatMap

Tags: scala, collections

I have class with field of type `Set[String]`. Also, I have list of objects of this class. I'd like to collect all strings from all sets of these objects into one set. Here is how I can do it already:

```
case class MyClass(field: Set[String])

val list = List(
  MyClass(Set("123")),
  MyClass(Set("456", "798")),
  MyClass(Set("123", "798"))
)

list.flatMap(_.field).toSet // Set(123, 456, 798)
```

It works, but I think, I can achieve the same using only `flatMap`, without `toSet` invocation. I tried this, but it had given compilation error:

```
// error: Cannot construct a collection of type Set[String]
// with elements of type String based on a collection of type List[MyClass].
list.flatMap[String, Set[String]](_.field)
```

If I change type of `list` to `Set` (i.e., `val list = Set(...)`), then such `flatMap` invocation works.

So, can I use somehow `Set.canBuildFrom` or any other `CanBuildFrom` object to invoke `flatMap` on `List` object, so that I'll get `Set` as a result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `CanBuildFrom` instance you want is called `breakOut` and has to be provided as a second parameter:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut

case class MyClass(field: Set[String])

val list = List(
  MyClass(Set("123")),
  MyClass(Set("456", "798")),
  MyClass(Set("123", "798"))
)

val s: Set[String] = list.flatMap(_.field)(breakOut)
```

Note that explicit type annotation on variable `s` is mandatory - that's how the type is chosen.

**Edit:**

If you're using `Scalaz` or `cats`, you can use `foldMap` as well:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
list.foldMap(_.field)
```

This does essentially what `mdm`s answer proposes, except the `Set.empty` and `++` parts are already baked in.

Answer (score 4):

The way flatMap work in Scala is that it can only remove one wrapper for the same type of wrappers i.e. `List[List[String]] -> flatMap -> List[String]`

if you apply flatMap on different wrapper data types then you will always get the final outcome as higher level wrapper data type i.e.`List[Set[String]] -> flatMap -> List[String]`

if you want to apply the flatMap on different wrapper type  i.e. `List[Set[String]] -> flatMap -> Set[String]` in you have 2 options :-

1. Explicitly cast the one datatype wrapper to another i.e. `list.flatMap(_.field).toSet` or
2. By providing implicit converter ie. `implicit def listToSet(list: List[String]): Set[String] = list.toSet` and the you can get `val set:Set[String] = list.flatMap(_.field)`

only then what you are trying to achieve will be accomplished.

**Conclusion:-** if you apply flatMap on 2 wrapped data type then you will always get the final result as op type which is on top of wrapper data type i.e. `List[Set[String]] -> flatMap -> List[String]` and if you want to convert or cast to different datatype then either you need to implicitly or explicitly cast it.

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe provide a specific `CanBuildFrom`, but why not to use a fold instead?

```
list.foldLeft(Set.empty[String]){case (set, myClass) => set ++ myClass.field}
```

Still just one pass through the collection, and if you are sure the `list` is not empty, you could even user `reduceLeft` instead.

Comment: There's no need to use `case` here since `foldLeft` accepts function with two parameters, i.e. `(_ ++ _.field)`

Comment: you are certainly right @Oleg, but I made it explicit just for clarity's sake.

Comment: you can still omit "case" keyword, since you're not doing any significant pattern matching